# I created a spring boot application in which I am trying to list the files from a location

Tags: java, spring, url, syntax, postman

Below is the method I am using to list the files from the directory (this code is in my service class):

```
public Set<String> listOfFilesOnPrem(String dir) {
    return Stream.of(new File(dir).listFiles())
            .filter(file -> !file.isDirectory())
            .map(File::getName)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

And below is the code I am using to trigger this in my controller.class:

```
@GetMapping("/onprem/list/files")
public ResponseEntity<Set<String>> getListOfFilesOnPrem(@RequestParam String dir) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(service.listOfFilesOnPrem(dir), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

This is failing because the string I am passing as a requestparam is of this format:
`\\long.....\...\.....\....`

And it fails due to the `\\` at the beginning

I got to know this by removing characters from URL and triggering the endpoint again from postman until I got a hit to my debugger.

Can you help me get around this problem?

Comment: what problem? you just said yourself it's caused by the "\\" and that you solved it by removing one of the backslashes?

Comment: when I removed one "\" it didnt solve the problem . It just made the URL valid... but in order for me to access particular location it needs to be as it was with \\. With just one \ its not a valid location